# Stubbing out a method from a module in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In my rails project I have a presenter method that has a helper view method in it. This helper method is already tested so I would like to stub out it out in my test.  How may I write this in my spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to stub it in your view spec then how about something like this:

```
before(:each) do
  view.stub!(:my_helper).and_return(something)
end
```